# django + html rendering

Tags: html, css, django

How do I make the the first nav pill in my nav active?

I've tried adding class="active", but that just makes all nav pills active.

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-dark">
        <div class="container text-center menu-meals">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills">
                {% for menu in menus %}
                    {% if menu.mealtype %}
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#{{ menu.mealtype }}" aria-controls="{{ menu.mealtype }}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{ menu.mealtype }}</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by adding id="menu-meals" to my  and then added a script.

```
<script>
        $(function () {
              $('#menu-meals li:eq(0) a').tab('show');
           });
    </script>
```